# I receive the error AADSTS50020 when authenticating in an azure app registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have this error when I try to login in an app that I’ve created in App registration in azure:

> AADSTS50020: User account '***@hotmail.com' from identity provider
> 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'NAMETENANT' and cannot access the
> application 'CLIENTID'(NAMEAPP) in that tenant. The account needs to
> be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in
> again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

The login process I use is the authorization code flow:

1. ```
   Generate code:
   ```

GET:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode?client_id=CLIENTID

form-encode:

client_id, scope

And when I enter the code I receive the error: AADSTS50020. These are my settings in azure portal: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhpypwlrW5KohIEh6wPVtvoe1R-RPA?e=FLQ0sD

I want that any Microsoft account(personal or 365) can be used but if is not possible with personal account I’m good. This is my first time using azure so I’m not sure what I’m missing, I have a free account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

The error usually occurs if the Azure AD Application is not configured to authorize multi-Tenant (*other organizations/personal accounts users*) or not using **`common`** endpoint.

To resolve the error, try configuring the Azure AD Application as "***Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts***" like below:

[image]

And make sure to use **common** endpoint while authorizing the users like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 

client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

***The code got generated successfully by using personal accounts like below:***

[image]

**Note** that :

- For **Single Tenant Applications** make use of TenantID authorize endpoint and register application as *Accounts in this organizational directory only (Contoso only - Single tenant)* and use **`TenantID`** endpoint.
- For **Multi-Tenant Applications** (for other organizations) register application as *Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)* and **`organizations`** endpoint.
- For **Multi-Tenant Applications** (for other organization and personal accounts) register application as *(Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)* and use **`common`** endpoint.

When I tried to use **`TenantID` authorize endpoint** and used **Personal account** to login with, I got the error like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenanID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 

client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Microsoft Entra ID (Single Tenant) identity provider in your signup_signin policy.

To fix this error, you have to use Microsoft Entra ID ( multi-tenant ) identity provider, as explained in the [Microsoft Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#register-a-microsoft-entra-app).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35386589)

Comment: The other existing answer is sufficient, why add another , and that too with little details?